docker login to Nexus: 503 Service Unavailable
Docker Login to Nexus Fails with 503 Error
I'm trying to log in to a Nexus repository using Docker:
docker login xxx.xxxx.com
However, I keep encountering the following error:
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://xxx.xxx.com/v2/ failed with status: 503 Service Unavailable
Additional Context:

I am using AnyConnect Cisco VPN
When I was in office it worked fine. I think VPN could messed it up a bit.
I am using WSL 2 on Windows 10
Prior to this issue, while using VPN, I couldn't ping anything from the WSL console. This problem did not occur in the office without VPN.
I managed to resolve the ping issue in WSL by adjusting the network
interface metrics using the following PowerShell commands:

Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)" | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 1
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 6000
I ran a curl request to the same endpoint and received this response:
curl -v https://xxx.xxx.com/v2/

* Connected to xxx.xxx.com port 443 (#0)
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.xxx.com
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: xxx.xxx.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0

< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< content-type: text/html
< cache-control: no-cache
< content-length: 104
< Set-cookie: defId=dot; max-age=60; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>No server is available to handle this request.</body></html>

What I Have Tried:

Ping to xxx.xxx.com works fine (after fixing with commands).
Logging into the web interface for xxx.xxx.com works perfectly.

I have tried to fix this for a whole day, but at this point, I am running out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time and help.
